# PANDAS reshaping data field day

Tags: python, pandas

Sample data-set:

```
data = {"id":{"0":"1234","1":"1234","2":"4567","3":"4567","4":"4567","5":"89123","6":"89123","7":"89123","8":"18749"},"name":{"0":"bob","1":"rob","2":"bob","3":"rob","4":"sam","5":"bob","6":"rob","7":"sam","8":"dick"}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

The solution should have each unique value from the id column as a column, and then each associated value from the name column as the values for that row.

I know I can do this a number of ways, the purpose of me asking this is to see examples of hopefully all the different ways that this is possible.

For example, I saw this:

```
df.groupby('id')['name'].apply(list)
```

I found it to be a really cool solution, but I'm not exactly sure what's going on. I presume it is applying a function that converts all the values associated with each id value into a list. I would also like to know how to use stack, unstack, transpose and pivot to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**reconstruct**

```
pd.Series(df.name.values, [df.index, df.id.values]).unstack()

   1234 18749  4567 89123
0   bob  None  None  None
1   rob  None  None  None
2  None  None   bob  None
3  None  None   rob  None
4  None  None   sam  None
5  None  None  None   bob
6  None  None  None   rob
7  None  None  None   sam
8  None  dick  None  None
```

**`set_index`**

```
df.set_index('id', append=True).name.unstack()

   1234 18749  4567 89123
0   bob  None  None  None
1   rob  None  None  None
2  None  None   bob  None
3  None  None   rob  None
4  None  None   sam  None
5  None  None  None   bob
6  None  None  None   rob
7  None  None  None   sam
8  None  dick  None  None
```

---

**`fill_value=''`**

```
df.set_index('id', append=True).name.unstack(fill_value='')

id 1234 18749 4567 89123
0   bob                 
1   rob                 
2              bob      
3              rob      
4              sam      
5                    bob
6                    rob
7                    sam
8        dick
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using pivot.

```
df.pivot(columns='id',values='name')
Out[280]: 
id  1234 18749  4567 89123
0    bob  None  None  None
1    rob  None  None  None
2   None  None   bob  None
3   None  None   rob  None
4   None  None   sam  None
5   None  None  None   bob
6   None  None  None   rob
7   None  None  None   sam
8   None  dick  None  None
```